# qTip2 positioning with ajax

Tags: jquery, qtip, qtip2

I am creating a tooltip for a set of menus and the content is loaded from an ajax call. I need the content to refresh every time the tooltip is created. I am using this guide: http://qtip2.com/guides#content.ajax.loading (Right above where it says "Grab content continuousl")

It works, the content is loaded, however the positioning of the tooltip doesn't change such that the arrow is off-centered. The tooltip grows only to the right and doesn't re-position itself.

The code:

```
$('.dropdown').qtip({
    overwrite: true,
    position: {
        effect: false,
        my: 'top center',  // Position my top left...
        at: 'bottom center' // at the bottom right of...
    },
    style: 'qtip-menu',
    show: {
        delay: 200
    },
    hide: {
        delay: 200,
        fixed: true
    },
    content: {
        text: function(event, api) {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            api.elements.content.html('Loading...');

            return $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<?=base_url();?>loadajax/menu',
                data: { id: id }
            })
            .done(function(html) {
                return html;
            })
                .then(function(content) {
                    return content
                }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                    api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                })
            .always(function() {
                $('.dropdown').qtip('reposition');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you can tell, I tried re-positioning after the success of the ajax call, doesn't do anything tough.

Comment: I have not, I thought I did but it didn't work

Comment: This can help: https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/issues/611

Answer (score 0):

You should use events to update content.

Here an example:

```
        var xhr = null;
        $('#dialog').qtip({
            position: {
                effect: false,
                my: 'top center',  // Position my top left...
                at: 'bottom center' // at the bottom right of...
            },
            style: 'qtip-menu',
            show: {
                delay: 200
            },
            hide: {
                delay: 200,
                fixed: true
            },
            content: 'Loading...',
            events: {
                show: function(event, api){
                    api.set('content.text', 'Loading...');
                    api.reposition();
                    xhr = $.ajax({
                        url: '/echo/html/',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {
                            html: "<ul><li>element1</li><li>element2</li><li>element3 very very very long</li></ul>",
                            delay: 1
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                            if(status !== 'abort'){
                                api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                                api.reposition();
                            }
                        },
                        success: function(html){
                            api.elements.content.html(html);
                            api.reposition();
                        }
                    });
                },
                hide: function(event, api) {
                    if(xhr){
                        xhr.abort();
                    } 
                }
            }
        });
```

And the full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ztpyd59w/